# node js mssql output parameter returns null value

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I am trying to insert details into db and after that i need to get out put parameter value but after implementing the below code i was successfully inserts into db but output parameter has null value.

I check in db code works fine but in node js i see that there is null value.

I am using mssql package

Below is code..

```
            sql.close();
            sql.connect(config, function (err) {

                if (err) console.log(err);
                  //create Request object
                var request = new sql.Request();

                console.log(EXCEL_ROWS);

                request.input('p_Flag', sql.VarChar, UpdateQualityExcel_Flag)
                request.input('p_ProjectCode', sql.NVarChar, EXCEL_ROWS.PROJECT_CODE);
                request.input('p_ActivityId',sql.INT,EXCEL_ROWS.ACTIVITY_ID);
                request.input('p_ActivityName', sql.VarChar, EXCEL_ROWS.ACTIVITY_NAME);
                request.output('po_Message',sql.VarChar)
                request.output('po_ActivityClosed',sql.INT)

                // query to the database and get the records
                request.execute("[dbo].[ARA_SP_ACTION_QualityExcelUpdate]").then(function(recordSet) {

                      if (recordSet == null || recordSet.length === 0)
                        return;

                    console.log(request.parameters.po_ActivityClosed.value)


                }).catch(function (err) {         
                    console.log(err);

                });
```

**output:**
  null

Comment: which sql package are you using ?

Comment: I am mssql package

Comment: Does the stored proc include `SET NOCOUNT ON`? If not, try adding it.

Comment: i have added SET NOCOUNT ON but no luck.. i think sp is fine ,somewhere i missed in node js itself

Comment: I am also facing same issue, Had you managed to solve ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  export const updateRequerimientoById = async (req, res) => {

    const { Id_Cliente, Id_CentroComercial, Descripcion, Situacion } = req.body;
  
    if ( Descripcion == null ) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Solicitud incorrecta. Por favor llena todos los campos" });
    }
  
    try {
      
      const pool = await getConnection();
      await pool.request()
        .input("Id_Requerimiento", sql.Int, req.params.id_requerimiento)
        .input("Id_Cliente", sql.Int, Id_Cliente)
        .input("Id_CentroComercial", sql.Int, Id_CentroComercial)
        .input("Descripcion", sql.Text, Descripcion)
        .input("Situacion", sql.Int, Situacion)
        .output("Id_Resultado",sql.Int)
        .output("Result_Codigo",sql.Int)
        .output("Result_Mensaje",sql.VarChar(100))

        .execute(requerimientoquerys.updateRequerimientoById, function(err, recordsets, returnValue) {

          const summary = {
            Result: recordsets.output,
            Record: recordsets.output["Result_Codigo"] === 200 ? req.body : {} 
          };

          res.json(summary);

        });

    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500);
      res.send(error.message);
    }
  };
```

```
{
    "Result": {
        "Id_Resultado": 12,
        "Result_Codigo": 200,
        "Result_Mensaje": "Actualización realizada con exito."
    },
    "Record": {
        "Id_Cliente": 1,
        "Id_CentroComercial": 1,
        "Descripcion": "POSTMAN POSTMAN 10 EXITOS",
        "Situacion": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the [edit] link instead of adding another post

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).